# How to check if serial port is already open (by another process) in Linux, using Python 2.7 (and possibly pyserial)?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pyserial

I know there are other questions quite similar to mine, but none of them address the issue I'm having.

I'd like to use `pyserial` to access a serial port (`/dev/tty...`), but only on the condition that another process hasn't already opened it.

The following snippet returns four available ports on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, when run once. If I run it a second time I would expect no ports to be available. Sadly, the same list of ports are returned. It seems `pyserial` cannot identify that another process has already opened the port.

I'd expect a `SerialException` to be thrown, or the `isOpen()` method to return False, but `pyserial` happily opens the multiple times.

```
import serial
from serial import tools
from serial.tools import list_ports


def available_ttys():
    for tty in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
        try:
            port = serial.Serial(port=tty[0])
            if port.isOpen():
                yield port
        except serial.SerialException as ex:
            print 'Port {0} is unavailable: {1}'.format(tty, ex)


def main():
    ttys = []
    for tty in available_ttys():
        ttys.append(tty)
        print tty

    input('waiting ...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output regardless of how many times I run it in parallel:

```
Port ('/dev/ttyS31', 'ttyS31', 'n/a') is unavailable: Could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error')
...
Port ('/dev/ttyS0', 'ttyS0', 'n/a') is unavailable: Could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error')
Serial<id=0x7fca9d9f1c90, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
Serial<id=0x7fca9d9f1cd0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM2', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
Serial<id=0x7fca9d9f1e50, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
Serial<id=0x7fca9d9f1ed0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
waiting ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @VooDooNOFX said, there's no technical limitation on preventing the other processes from opening the same port (device). However, on Linux you can lock the file to prevent your application from using the same port multiple times.

```
import fcntl, serial

s = serial.Serial(0)
fcntl.flock(s.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

In this case, your application will try to obtain an exclusive lock (`LOCK_EX`) on the serial port. Thanks to `LOCK_NB`, the call will fail immediately if any other process has locked the serial port already — through raising `IOError` (or `BlockingIOError` sub-exception in Python 3.3).

This has two advantages over the other solution:

1. You are not introducing any non-standard files but use system-provided method which brings better interoperability,
2. The lock is immediately released when your process exits, so you don't have to worry about stale locks.

---

So, your function would look like:

```
def available_ttys():
    for tty in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
        try:
            port = serial.Serial(port=tty[0])
            if port.isOpen():
                try:
                    fcntl.flock(port.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                except IOError:
                    print 'Port {0} is busy'.format(tty)
                else:
                    yield port
        except serial.SerialException as ex:
            print 'Port {0} is unavailable: {1}'.format(tty, ex)
```

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing. It has worked well so far.

Comment: I tried the fcntl solution, but it only protects you if the other process also uses the same fcntl lock. If the other process opens the serial port without issues an flock call then when you try your flock will succeed even though the serial port is already open.

Comment: I have a RPi reading serial data from Arduino. This answer helped me prevent another process opening in the same port, however the new process disrupts the original one, so I get corrupted data. My addition to this code is to detect when the data are corrupted (JSON vs garbage), and then close `ser.close()` and reopen the serial port. Old thread, but someone may still lurk around :)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in Linux which prevents multiple processes from opening the same serial port. Hence why the pyserial library is capable of doing this. There is however a standard-ish convention which has been well documented elsewhere: https://superuser.com/questions/488908/sharing-a-serial-port-between-two-processes

The generic process requires you to open the device, then create a text file in `/tmp` or `/var/lock` directories which contains your PID. The second script will search for the existence of this file, and refuse to open the port of it exists.

For much more information, see: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-13.html

Comment: Thank you for the information on the standard-ish convention. I'll keep it in mind. The `fcntl exclusive` seems easier to implement, so I'll have a go with that.